# Running LLama2 on a GeForce 1080 8Gb machine

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface, llama

I am trying to run LLama2 on my server which has mentioned nvidia card. It's a simple hello world case you can find [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2). However I am constantly running into memory issues:

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 250.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.92 GiB total capacity; 7.12 GiB already allocated; 241.62 MiB free; 7.18 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I tried

export PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:128

but same effect. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this source](https://easywithai.com/resources/llama-2/):

> The model you use will vary depending on your hardware. For good
> results, you should have at least 10GB VRAM at a minimum for the 7B
> model, though you can sometimes see success with 8GB VRAM.

In order to lower the memory footprint of the model, I first recommend that you try running the model in half precision (if supported) with a batch size of one. If you still experience `CUDA out of memory` I suggest you to try with a quantized version of the model, like for example [these ones](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-GGML/tree/main).